# CallsFake not triggered for function inside promise resolve

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to rewrite a codebase from callbacks to promises, but even tho the code is working fine, the sinon test is failing due to not triggering the callFake method.

In the code there is snippet:

```
notificationDBService.deleteNotification()
  .then(function() { || () => { //Both don't work
    console.log('resolved'); // Is logged
    notificationService.insertNotificationDB()
  });
```

In my mocha test I have:

```
 sinon.stub(notificationDBService, 'insertNotificationDB').callsFake((n, callback) => {
  insertNotificationNote = n;
  insertNotificationCallCount++;
  callback();
});
```

The callFake function is never called, it was when I had it setup with callbacks instead:

```
notificationDBService.deleteNotificationsByProjectIDAndBranch(projectID, projectBranch,
(err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    logger.error(`Could not delete build notifications for: ${projectID} - ${projectBranch}. ${message}`, err);
  } else {
    notificationDBService.insertNotificationDB()
```

Any ideas why the callFake method is no longer working?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are stubbing `notificationDBService`, and you were calling `notificationDBService.insertNotificationDB` in the non-promised version, but in the promised version you're calling `notificationService.insertNotificationDB()` - i.e. looks to me like a typo (missing `DB` in the variable name)?